# SHA1 hashing in SQLite: how?

Tags: c#, sqlite, cryptography, hash, sha1

Working with several DBs in parallel and need to initialize some records with hashed passwords. In `MS SQL server` there are handy functions that allow to hash on the fly:

```
HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar(32), N'admin'))
```

Is there is a similar function with `SQLite`?

If not, which is the easiest workaround (such as select from `SQL server` and somehow insert it into `SQLite` tables)?

The preferred hashing algorithm is `SHA1` and the passwords are stored in a `BLOB` column.

Update: I use C# language in the current project.

Comment: SHA-1 is not an encryption but a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: SHA1 is not a good choice to hash passwords, because it is ways to fast, and therefore makes brute-forcing easy. Have a look at key derivation functions like BCrypt or PBKDF2, the latter is built in in C#, for BCrypt libraries are available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such function built into SQLite3.

But you could define a user function e.g. with [`sqlite3_create_function`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) if you're using the C interface, and implement SHA-1 with that. (But if you're having a programmable interface perhaps you could just SHA-1 the password outside of the SQL engine.)

You could also try to find / create an extension and load with [the `load_extension` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension), but I don't have experience on that.

Edit:

- See [this answer on *SQLiteFunction Simple Not Working*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943704/sqlitefunction-simple-not-working/1943742#1943742) for how to define a custom function with `System.Data.SQLite` in C#.
- Use [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) to compute the SHA-1 hash.

Answer (score 7):

Noting that sqlite  does have a `sha1()` extension added in 2017

https://www.sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/sha1.c

although it may not be enabled by default.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite does not come with SHA1, but it is relatively easily to add.  You didn't say what language, you're using, but you can look at the C documentation for [create_function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) and [sqlite3_result](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/result_blob.html).  You can also take a look at [this example](http://www.copiousfreetime.org/articles/2009/01/10/writing-sql-functions-in-ruby.html) of how to add SHA1 to SQLite using Ruby.

With [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), they're called user-defined functions.  You can look at [this example](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/348/1457.aspx#1457) on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom function for SHA1 in C# like this:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "Sha1", Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class Sha1 : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        var buffer = args[0] as byte[];

        if ( buffer == null )
        {
            var s = args[0] as string;

            if ( s != null )
                buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
        }

        if ( buffer == null )
            return null;

        using ( var sha1 = SHA1.Create() )
        {
            return sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

This function can be called for binary data or strings. Strings are hashed in their Unicode representation. This should match SQL Server.

The function can be called like this:

```
select sha1('abc')
select sha1(x'010203')
```

Answer (score 2):

The following builds latest sqlite with dynamic library support, and compiles [sha1 extension](https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/misc/sha1.c). It also assumes debian-based linux distribution:

```sh
sudo apt build-dep sqlite3 # fetches dependencies to compile sqlite3

mkdir sqlite-compilation
cd    sqlite-compilation

wget -O sqlite.tar.gz https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz?r=release

tar xzf sqlite.tar.gz

mkdir build
cd    build
  ../sqlite/configure
  make OPTS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION'
  ./sqlite3 -cmd 'pragma compile_options;' <<< .exit
cd -

cd sqlite/ext/misc
  # https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/misc/sha1.c
  sed -i 's/int sqlite3_sha_init(/int sqlite3_extension_init(/' sha1.c # this is needed to give object file custom name, for example libSqlite3Sha1.so:
  gcc -g -O2 -shared -fPIC -I ../../../build -o libSqlite3Sha1.so ./sha1.c
  cp libSqlite3Sha1.so ../../../build/
cd -
```

In result you will have:

```sh
build/sqlite3           # sqlite3 binary
build/libSqlite3Sha1.so # sha1 extension
```

Test:

```sh
cd build
  sqlite3 <<< '
.load ./libSqlite3Sha1
select sha1(1);
.exit
  '
  # compare output with:
  echo -n 1 | sha1sum
cd -
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SQLite doesn't have any hashing functions built-in.

There is [a way](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to add custom functions to SQLite, but it's probably easier if you just calculate the SHA1 hash in your program and store it in SQlite.

Creating custom functions for SQLite depends somewhat on the API and the language you're using. I only have experience with creating SQLite functions from Python.