# Java JDBC/SQLite: Any inbuilt function to hash strings

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using Java to read & write to an SQLite3 database. I am using the SQLiteJDBC Java driver to interact with the database.

**Are there any hash functions built into the SQLiteJDBC Java JDBC driver that I can use to prevent against SQL Injection attacks?**

I come from using python & its inbuilt SQLite3 module/library. That library has its own SQLite hash function, so does SQLiteJDBC Java JDBC driver have its own in built hash function.

If not, does anyone have any ideas what I could use to hash the data that I store on the database so I can avoid injection attacks?

Comment: hash to prevent injection attacks??? You use prepared statements to prevent injection attacks. Hash functions are used to avoid storing passwords in the clear. Perhaps you have the two confused?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there isn't. SQLite3 doesn't have it built in.

You might be able to find what you're looking for here: [SHA1 hashing in SQLite: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179021/sha1-hashing-in-sqlite-how)