# MD5 function in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, md5, user-defined-functions

I am trying to port some sql from MySQL to SQLite, however we use mysql's `md5()` function, which doesn't exist in sqlite.

I've seen references to people recompiling sqlite to include this function, and I think it's possible to include user defined functions in sqlite (right?). So how do I go about adding `md5()` to sqlite? I'd rather not have to recompile the sqlite installed by my package manager, is it possible to have md5 without doing this?

Answer (score 8):

I have created an extension for sqlite using openssl functions.
You may [check it out here](http://www.swhistlesoft.com/blog/2011/01/07/54-sqlite-hashing-functions-library)!

Be forewarned, you need a compiler and some knowledge of how to use one. I can provide some assistance if you need - just post a comment.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite doesn't have any built-in hashing functionality. But as you correctly said you could define a user function. See this SO answer for more details:

- [SHA1 hashing in SQLite: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179021/sha1-hashing-in-sqlite-how/3179047#3179047)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

The following builds latest sqlite with dynamic library support, and compiles [md5 extension](https://github.com/moisseev/sqlite-md5). It also assumes debian-based linux distributive:

```sh
sudo apt build-dep sqlite3 # fetches dependencies to compile sqlite3

mkdir sqlite-compilation
cd    sqlite-compilation

wget -O sqlite.tar.gz https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz?r=release

tar xzf sqlite.tar.gz

mkdir build
cd    build
  ../sqlite/configure
  make OPTS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION'
  ./sqlite3 -cmd 'pragma compile_options;' <<< .exit
cd -

# https://github.com/moisseev/sqlite-md5
cd sqlite/ext
  wget -O sqlite-md5-master.zip https://github.com/moisseev/sqlite-md5/archive/master.zip
  unzip   sqlite-md5-master.zip
  cd      sqlite-md5-master
    gcc -lm -fPIC -shared md5.c -o libSqlite3Md5.so
    cp libSqlite3Md5.so ../../../build/
  cd -
cd ../../
```

In result you will have:

```sh
build/sqlite3          # sqlite3 binary
build/libSqlite3Md5.so # md5 extension
```

Test:

```sh
cd build
  sqlite3 <<< '
.load ./libSqlite3Md5
select hex(md5(1));
.exit
  '
  # compare output with:
  echo -n 1 | md5sum
cd -
```

Comment: Had this error:
sqlite3ext.h:20:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
 #include "sqlite3.h"
When I fixed by copying the file to cp ./build/sqlite3.h ~/sqlite-compilation/sqlite/ext/sqlite-md5-master/
it worked.

Comment: @shinguz strange, I just copy-pasted that code to my other computer, and it worked with no modification.

Comment: I set-up the system from scratch. Can it be that you have the .h file somewhere in the default paths? It is also possible that I was just tired and did it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The [sqlite-hashes](https://github.com/nyurik/sqlite-hashes#readme) is a loadable extension that adds `MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, FNV1a, XXHASH` to SQLite (or you can use it from Rust code directly).

This would allow you to use SQL to get a hash without dealing with it in code:

- `SELECT md5(data) FROM tbl`

(Disclaimer: I'm the author)