# Call R functions from sqldf queries

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf

Is there a way to call R functions from sqldf queries?  E.g.

```
sqldf("select paste('Hello', 'World')")
```

Or, is there a way to define custom functions or stored procedures within the SQLite engine behind sqldf?  (I am using sqldf with plain old in-memory R data frames; I'm not connecting to any actual databases.)

Comment: Why would you use R functions rather than the built in SQLite functions?

Comment: I think the answer is simply, no.

Comment: joran: actually, the particular function I'm interested in is digest() from the digest R package, to compute MD5 hashes

Comment: Ok, then I agree with @nograpes.

Comment: If you want to call R code inside SQL queries then use PostreSQL plus pl/r and if you want to do it from R check  the `RPostgreSQL` packages (also possible with `sqldf`)

Comment: I suppose, then, that the workaround is to create additional columns in my dataframe e.g. mydf["hashedpassword"] <- digest(mydf$password)

Comment: Oops, need an sapply: mydf["hashedpassword"] <- sapply(mydf$password, digest(x))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*1) Existing Functions* First make sure that the function you want is not already available.  For example the code in the question is directly supported in SQL already:

```
> sqldf("select 'Hello' || ' ' || 'world' ")
  'Hello' || ' ' || 'world'
1               Hello world
```

*2) RSQLite.extfuns*  One has all the SQL functions from sqlite's version of SQL plus a large number of user defined functions out of the box listed in `?initExtension` in the RSQLite package.

*3) Other Loadable Extensions*  Functions in any existing sqlite loadable extensions can be loaded via the sqlite SQL function `load_extension()`.  e.g. see [these extensions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/)

*4) Custom functions*  Custom functions can be added to SQLite but they must be written [in C](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).

*5) PostgreSQL & sqldf* sqldf supports not just sqlite but also h2, postgresql and mysql.  postgresql is particularly powerful in this respect. See [this link from the postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/xfunc.html)  Also see [Pl/R](http://bunsen.credativ.com/~jco/2011/plr-PostgresOpen-2011.pdf) and [R Embedded Postgres package](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPostgres/).

*6) H2 & sqldf*  The H2 database is supported by sqldf.  Like sqlite H2 is included right in the RH2 driver R package so you don't have to install a separate database; however, you do have to install Java.  It has a builtin SHA256 hash function (called hash).

*7) mix sqldf & R*  sql and R can be mixed like this:

```
library(digest)
transform(sqldf("select * from BOD"), digest = sapply(demand, digest))
```

*8) Other*  See this [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179021/sha1-hashing-in-sqlite-how)

*UPDATE*:  Added info on H2.