# C# SQLite encryption hashing SHA1

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, hash, sha1

I have an application in C# and a database in SQLite. In database, I have a table with a few columns. In one of a columns, I have a value which is encrypted with SHA1 from query. But I need to use it in my C# app like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from accounts where (username=@username and password=sha1(@password));";
```

I need to select the string value, for logging to app. I receive error: `no such function sha1`.

From other posts like: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179021/sha1-hashing-in-sqlite-how) , I understand that I have to create another function for hashing with sha1? But I don't really understand how to do this..Can anybody help me? Sorry if it's duplicate but I didn't find the specified answer.

Comment: Use `Select * from accounts where (username=@username and password=@password);` and bind the hashed value for `@password`

Comment: And in most case using a hash function such as `SHA1`, is considered insecure for storing password, learn about [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), which are considered more secured for password storage.

Comment: You mean like this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sha1(@password)", password);` or `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sha1("@password"), password);` ??

Comment: Thank you dvhh for your suggestion!

Comment: Can you also give me a quick example of how to use that key derivation?

Comment: use `Select * from accounts where (username=@username and password=@password);` as a query without `sha1` in the query and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@password",sha1(password)");`, meaning that you would have to apply sha1 in the c# code, rather than in SQL.

Comment: Syntax for cmd is not correct. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", sha1(password));` Error: `sha1 doesn't exist in current context`

Comment: password is actually textBox1.Text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73529/discussion-between-dvhh-and-user272976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SQLite does not implement any `sha1` function by default, you would have to move the password hashing from the **SQL** query to your code.

Meaning your query should be :

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from accounts where (username=@username and password=@password);";
```

and you should pass the password like this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", sha1(password));
```

And you should implement your own `sha1` function

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...

string sha1(string input) {
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    string result="";
    using (HashAlgorithm hash = SHA1.Create()) {
        result=Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(byteArray));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Important**

Using hashing function is considered quite **insecure** for storing password, you should consider learning about [Key Derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), reading the wikipedia pages will lead you to C# implementation of such functions.

Comment: One problem, I tried just for my curiosity to use sha1 with that `stirng sha1(string input) {}` but I receive error: `sha1(string) is a method, which is not valid in the given context`. Why?

Comment: Sorry for the name conlict, I have amended my answer

Comment: Yes, code is ok, but it doesn't recognized my value from table. I think here is the problem: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", sha1(password));` I receive: `Incorrect username or password`