# Delete a file from a SQL trigger in SQLite

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlite

Is it possible to delete a file from the filesystem in a SQL trigger in SQLite?

I have a table which contains the path to a file. Is it possible to create a trigger that starts when a deletion occurs and that deletes the file whose path is the one contained in the deleted row? How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a user-defined function that will take care of deleting the file and call it from the trigger.

Here is an example: [SQLiteFunction Simple Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943704/sqlitefunction-simple-not-working)

Comment: I'm programming in C++, so following your answer I was able to refine my search and found this: http://blog.renanfernandes.com.br/2010/09/criando-user-defined-functions-do-sqlite3-no-qt/. Works great! Thanks for your help!